# How to get dev.*.domain.com to work on nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to make nginx accept websites in this format: dev.*.domain.com. I've read the docs and I understand that I have to use a regex for that.

> A wildcard name may contain an asterisk only on the name's start or
>   end, and only on a dot border. The names “www.*.example.org” and
>   “w*.example.org” are invalid. However, these names can be specified
>   using regular expressions, for example, “~^www..+.example.org$” and
>   “~^w.*.example.org$”. An asterisk can match several name parts. The
>   name “*.example.org” matches not only www.example.org but
>   www.sub.example.org as well.

So I have:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name ~^dev\..+\.domain\.com\.br$ dev.domain.com.br;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/dev.domain.com.br.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/dev.domain.com.br.error.log;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:68319/;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
        }
        location /media/ {
            alias /my/folder/to/media/;
            expires 15d;
        }
        location /favicon.ico { 
            alias /my/folder/to/favicon.ico;
            expires 15d;
        }
    }
```

Somehow it ends being catched by this rule (which is the last one):

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name *.domain.com.br domain.com.br;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.com.br.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.com.br.error.log;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
        }
        location /media/ {
            alias /my/path/to/media/;
            expires 15d;
        }
        location /favicon.ico { 
            alias /my/path/to/favicon.ico;
            expires 15d;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance.

PS: I think it's being catched by *.domain.com because of the order nginx tests for matches. Is there anyway I can rewrite *.domain.com to only test for 1 subdomain level? i.e. test.domain.com matches *.domain.com, but sub.test.domain.com doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*.domain.com is just a simple suffix match, there's no way to limit it to a single subdomain level.  To accomplish what you want, you'll have to convert your suffix check to also be a regex:

```
server {
  server_name ~^dev\..+\.domain\.com\.br$ dev.domain.com.br;
  ...
}

server {
  server_name ~^[^.]+\.domain\.com\.br$ domain.com.br;
  ...
}
```

with both checks being regex, the order of the server blocks matters.